# Print value based on the coloumns value - MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

if the C2 column value is '03' i want to print it as 'K9' and if its value is 'O4' then i want to print it as 'k10' else any other values, it should show it.

how can i do that..

```
        //my code//
select a.capacity,a.comment, b.c1,b.c2,b.c3 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.capacity=b.capacity WHERE a.capacity= $name

      $rs = mysql_query( $sql ) or die('Database Error: ' . mysql_error());


        $num = mysql_num_rows( $rs );

        if($num >= 1 ){
            echo "";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs )){
        echo "<table>
            <tr>
                <th align='left' valign='middle'>Capacity</th>
                <td align='left' valign='middle'>$row[capacity]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align='left' valign='middle'>C2</th>
               <td align='left' valign='middle'>$row[c2]</td>
                </tr>               
            </table>";
         }
```

Comment: translate the first sentence from plain english to PHP code and you're set. really.

Comment: what are switch case and if-else for ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace with this while loop and check, may it will be work for you :

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs )){
    $row['c2'] = ( $row['c2'] == '03') ? 'K9' : $row['c2'] ;
    $row['c2'] = ( $row['c2'] == 'O4') ? 'k10' : $row['c2'] ;
    echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' valign='middle'>Capacity</th>
            <td align='left' valign='middle'>$row[capacity]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' valign='middle'>C2</th>
           <td align='left' valign='middle'>$row[c2]</td>
            </tr>               
        </table>";
     }
```

Comment: thanks kishan. stackoverflow is asking 5 more min to select this as answer. ok. b/w will this work `$row[c2] = ( $row[c2] == '03') ? 'K9' : $row[c3] ;
    $row[c2] = ( $row[c2] == 'O4') ? 'k10' : $row[c3] ;`

i mean can i print thise values in another column.

Comment: Yes, you can give any column value to `$row[c2]' column.

Comment: Ohh actually you need to use `$row['c2']` instead of `$row[c2]` and `$row['c3']` instead of `$row[c3]`. It give some time errors.